# Ant task to configure RabbitMQ

Tags: ant, rabbitmq

I am setting up my local build using Ant and have decided to use RabbitMQ. I would like to have any Ant task that I can use to configure my local installation for setting things up (stop, start, create queues etc..)  and tearing them down as part of my test suite.

Has anyone come across anything like this?

Answer (score 1):

I described a scenario in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9756269/489888) there the op was looking for a way to declare queues and bindings without the overhead of doing it at runtime.

In my solution I use a console utility to perform the queue declarations and have this called from a build step in my build server when running builds and tests.

During the normal course of coding and integration testing from the IDE, I simply make sure that I have used the utility fairly recently to make sure the queues have been established as per the current XML definitions. My test setups ensure that the queues themselves are empty before running.

Hope this helps.
Steve

Answer (score 1):

Ant is a build tool.  While running your automated tests is generally part of a build process, the setup of your queues are part of your specification's context and should be included in your tests.  If you truly have a need to configure your exchanges and queues once before all test runs, many frameworks provide a facility to do this.

Comment: Derek - I will have to disagree with you on this. I have used ANT as a means of initiating by CIT on many occasions and this often involved setting up things like queues, applying DB updates etc.. Its a fairly standard way of building and testing things.