# RabbitMQ DeclareQueue and DeclareBind Slow

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

It's suggested to DeclareQueue() and DeclareBind() prior to such operations as BasicPublish() or BasicConsume(), because configurations are idempotent. It does function this way, but the downside appears to be a cut in performance from 15k messages per second to 1.5k on my machine. There seems to be no clear documentation on a workaround. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you cite your source for this recommendation?

Comment: The tutorials on the RabbitMQ site generally specify this pattern. It's quite probable that there are more elaborations elsewhere. What is needed is a lighter weight method of pre-detecting prior to declaring, although presumably if that existed then declarequeue would use it internally.

Answer (score 2):

I'm intrigued by the performance ramifications of this advice. I haven't tried it for myself but it doesn't surprise me that there is some impact though a factor of 10 is quite something.

I any case, we chose to ignore this advice in favour of using a utility script to create and bind queues based on definitions held in XML. Our build server would execute the utility against the target exchanges before deploying our codebase to it. 
Queues themselves are defined in a queue definition XML file and then we use app.config for our config utility to hold exchange, host and virtualhost information so that we can take advantage of XML transformations (using slow cheetah) to transform build specific versions for output.
This approach allows us to sync exchange configurations with our codebase without the impact of constant queue and binding declarations.

Hope this helps.
Steve

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will consider this path. So long as the robustness of detecting that a queue has disappeared since it was first initialized can be performed, that seems reasonable. Are you comfortable that your code can handle this well?

Comment: My integration tests call PurgeQueue in their respective setups. If a queue has, for some reason, been deleted then the integration tests will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call declare, bind, and consume, it has to communicate with the server, so doing this each time you publish or get a message would have some level of impact on your processes.

With reference to the [Java tutorials](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-java.html), each of the examples declare and bind the queues only once per producer and consumer for the lifetime of each, so I'm not sure where you might have seen this guidance.

That said, it is possible for an exchange or queue to be deleted out from under you.  If this is a concern, you could use error handling to re-declare the exchanges, queues and bindings to ensure such occurrence wouldn't crash your applications.